# Pivot SQL table (Rows into Columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I am currently returning data into a table in my SQL stored procedure. I am trying to pivot the rows into columns, and the columns into rows, but I am struggling to do so as a lot of the tutorials I am following to do this have laid out they're tables differently.

This is the select at the bottom of my stored procedure:

```
select 

(CASE WHEN [Fitter] IS NULL THEN (Select Distinct substring([First Name],1,1)+' '+[Second Name] from Fitters where [Fitter Id]=FitterId) ELSE Fitter END) AS Fitter,
sum([Install Sell]) as [Install Sell],
sum([Install Cost]) as [Install Cost],
sum([Install Cost Amt]) as Gross,
(select cast(CAST((TaxStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as CIS,
(select cast(CAST((VatStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as VAT,
sum([Install Cost Amt]) - (select cast(CAST((TaxStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) + (select cast(CAST((VatStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as FittersPay,
sum([Install Cost Amt]) + (select cast(CAST((VatStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as Datafile

from @TempTable
group by FitterId, Fitter, TaxStatus, VatStatus
```

This is the data it returns:
[image]

I would like for the columns to pivot as rows and the rows to pivot as columns...

I have searched around online and am struggling to figure this out, i was wondering if i could get some assistance with this please.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server @jarlh

Comment: Show sample data and desired output

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope that helps @PravinDeshmukh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by first unpivoting and then pivoting. Here is an example, that you can adjust yo your data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(col0 VARCHAR(20), col1 MONEY, col2 MONEY, col3 MONEY)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('aaaaaa', 1, 1.2, 0),
('bbbbbb', 2, 2.2, 0),
('cccccc', 3, 3.3, 100),
('dddddd', 4, 4.4, 0)

SELECT * FROM @t 

SELECT * FROM @t
UNPIVOT (a FOR b IN([col1],[col2],[col3])) up
PIVOT (MAX(a) FOR col0 IN([aaaaaa],[bbbbbb],[cccccc],[dddddd])) p
```

Output1:

```
col0    col1    col2    col3
aaaaaa  1.00    1.20    0.00
bbbbbb  2.00    2.20    0.00
cccccc  3.00    3.30    100.00
dddddd  4.00    4.40    0.00
```

Output2:

```
b       aaaaaa  bbbbbb  cccccc  dddddd
col1    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00
col2    1.20    2.20    3.30    4.40
col3    0.00    0.00    100.00  0.00
```

It depends on type of your data, but you could need to do it dynamically. There is plenty of examples on the site. Just search for `dynamic pivoting`.

**EDIT:**

Something like this:

```
select * from (
select 

(CASE WHEN [Fitter] IS NULL THEN (Select Distinct substring([First Name],1,1)+' '+[Second Name] from Fitters where [Fitter Id]=FitterId) ELSE Fitter END) AS Fitter,
sum([Install Sell]) as [Install Sell],
sum([Install Cost]) as [Install Cost],
sum([Install Cost Amt]) as Gross,
(select cast(CAST((TaxStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as CIS,
(select cast(CAST((VatStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as VAT,
sum([Install Cost Amt]) - (select cast(CAST((TaxStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) + (select cast(CAST((VatStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as FittersPay,
sum([Install Cost Amt]) + (select cast(CAST((VatStatus/100 * sum([Install Cost Amt])) as decimal(18,5)) as float)) as Datafile

from @TempTable
group by FitterId, Fitter, TaxStatus, VatStatus) t

UNPIVOT (a FOR b IN([Install Sell],[Install Cost],[Gross]/*,...*/)) up
PIVOT (MAX(a) FOR Fitter IN([D Page],[J Hopley]/*,...*/)) p
```